# MYSQL Connector/NET 8.0.25 Upgrading failed

Tags: .net, mysql-connector

Can anyone please help me to resolve below error? I tried many times by uninstall and reinstall again but no luck.

**The action 'Upgrade' for product 'Connector/NET 8.0.25' failed.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems uninstalling the old version you can try running the "Microsoft Troubleshooter to install and uninstall programs", at present you can download from here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d

Once you uninstalled the old version you can install the newest version